# Improving the Speed of St Petersburg Simulations

Tags: r, performance, simulation

I am trying to write R functions to simulate the St Petersburg Paradox. In this paradox, we flip a fair coin until a tail appears for the first time. Each round, we get 2^n dollars.

I wrote an R function to do this:

```
    simulate_games <- function(n = 1000, max_turns = 10) {
    results <- data.frame(game_number = integer(), number_of_turns = integer(), final_reward = 

    numeric())
  
    for (i in 1:n) {
    turns <- 0
    reward <- 0
    
    while (turns < max_turns && runif(1) > 0.5) {
      turns <- turns + 1
      reward <- 2^(turns )
    }
    
    results <- rbind(results, data.frame(game_number = i, number_of_turns = turns, final_reward = reward))
    }
  
  return(results)
}
results <- simulate_games()
```

The final results I am interested in are:

```
c(mean(results$number_of_turns), mean(results$final_reward))
```

Now I am trying to speed up this simulation for a large number of "n":

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

simulate_games_parallel <- function(n = 1000000, max_turns = 10) {
    cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) 
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    
    results <- foreach(i = 1:n, .combine = rbind, .packages = "doParallel") %dopar% {
        turns <- 0
        reward <- 0
        
        while (turns < max_turns && runif(1) > 0.5) {
            turns <- turns + 1
            reward <- 2^(turns)
        }
        
        data.frame(game_number = i, number_of_turns = turns, final_reward = reward)
    }
    
    stopCluster(cl)
    return(results)
}

results <- simulate_games_parallel()
```

Am I doing this correctly? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the process, say, the number of `turns`, follows the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), and you can use `rgeom` for simulation

```
simulate_games <- function(n = 1000, max_turns = 10) {
    turns <- pmin(rgeom(n, 0.5), max_turns)
    rewards <- ifelse(turns == 0, 0, 2^turns)
    data.frame(
        game_number = seq.int(n),
        number_of_turns = turns,
        final_reward = rewards
    )
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I saw this analysis before based on the geometric distribution .... I was wondering if it was possible to parallelize the code I wrote the way I wrote it ... instead of taking the correct approach you did?

Comment: @pnaxso I am not familiar with code parallelization, but a `for` loop plus a `while` loop inside can hardly be significantly boosted.